# How to tied source code in war file?

Tags: java, ant

I have a JAVA project which deployed in WebSphere Application Server. When error occurs, the log shows me something like this:

```
[1/4/13 6:49:30:133 MYT] 0000003d theDaoImpl E org.huahsin.dao.impl.theInitDaoImpl getStatus [theInitDaoImpl:getStatus]
at org.huahsin.dao.impl.theInitDaoImpl.getStatus(Unknown Source)
```

This project was build using Ant and I have include the source code into this war file. May I know how could I tied the source code into the log so I could have a clearer picture what is happening on the particular function `getStatus()`.

Comment: You likely want to compile with debug information so that you know the source file and line number. By default ANT compile tasks don't include that information. Check the ANT task documentation to know how to enable it.

Comment: Compile with debug options. You can look up it in the [Ant Tasks doc](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you on hints from @Gimby and @ppeterka, I have the problem solved by putting the attribute `debug="on"` in `<javac>` tag.